# How to Wrap Flatlist items in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist, react-native-flexbox

I am trying to render the list of items like in this image.
[image]

Items in each row will vary based on their text size. [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) is using for rendering items.

**TagView.js**

```
<View style={styles.tagView}>
    <FlatList 
        scrollEventThrottle={1900} 
        data={this.state.interests} 
        numColumns={5}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View style={styles.tag}>
               <Text>{item.tagName}</Text>
           </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}
    />
</View>
```

**Style**

```
tagView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
},
tag: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 3,
    marginTop: 5
}
```

**Result**

[image]

But here items are not wrapping with device width. Is there any to wrap the contents?

Comment: Also try adding `alignItems: 'flex-start'` to the parent

Comment: @PritishVaidya Tried. Not working

Comment: I think they don't support it in `FlatList` for numerous reasons, check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13939). Alternative would be to use `ScrollView`

Answer (score 14):

FlatList with `columnWrapperStyle`

```
<FlatList 
    columnWrapperStyle={styles.tagView}
    scrollEventThrottle={1900} 
    data={this.state.interests} 
    numColumns={5}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <View style={styles.tag}>
           <Text>{item.tagName}</Text>
       </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}
/>
```

Style

```
tagView: {
  flexWrap: "wrap"
},
```

Comment: This should be accepted as best answer

Answer (score 4):

Add Horizontal Prop and try,

```
      <FlatList 
        scrollEventThrottle={1900} 
        data={this.state.interests} 
        numColumns={5}
        horizontal={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View style={styles.tag}>
               <Text>{item.tagName}</Text>
           </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}
    />
```

Comment: horizontal prop is using for rendering items next to each other horizontally instead of stacked vertically.

Comment: Yes so if you give horizontal={false} and numColumns={5}, it will give you a row with 5 values and then wrap.

Comment: @YogarajSaravanan Actually, using both props raises an error: `numColumns does not support horizontal`

Comment: This can still cause overlap with the last item in the row and the edge of the screen depending on the size of the items. Anyway to make sure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview) component for this purpose.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  {tags.map(({ id, name }) => (
     <Text key={id}>{name}</Text>
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: II can confirm that <scrollview> is the good way. I had the same question and change my Flatlist by ScroolView and it works perfectly. Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 0):

try scroolview and flatlist.

```
                <ScrollView
                  horizontal
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  contentContainerStyle={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                  }}>
                  <FlatList
                    data={this.state.carouselItems}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => `${item.id_news}`}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    numColumns={this.state.carouselItems.length / 2}
                  />
                </ScrollView>
```